# Proving that the counting measure is a measure on $\mathcal A$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here is the problem:
Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty set and $\mathcal A$ $=$ $\mathcal P$($\Omega$). Define $\mu$ on $\mathcal A$ by $\mu$($E$) equal to $N$($E$) if $E$ is finite and $\infty$ if $E$ is infinite, where $N$($E$) denotes the number of elements of E. Prove that $\mu$ is measurable on $\mathcal A$.

I have already proved the first two conditions for $\mu$ to be measurable on  $\mathcal A$.

However, I am stuck on proving the third condition [i.e $\mu($$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$) $=$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu$($E_n$)]

This is what I'm thinking:  Let $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets, and consider the following three cases:

1.) Suppose for some $k$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$, we have $N$($E_k$) = $\infty$.

2.) Suppose that for all $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$, we have $N$($E_n$) $<$ $\infty$, and that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $N$($E_n$)  $>$ $0$.

3.) Suppose that for all $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$, we have $N$($E_n$) $<$ $\infty$ and that there are finitely many $n$ such that $N$($E_n$)  $>$ $0$.

Comment: Good thinking so far. Did you do anything for any of those 3 cases?

Comment: @mike239x.  This is what I have for the first case:

Comment: @mike239x. (Sorry for the unfinished comment)  Following from the first case: it follows that $\mu$ =$(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n)$ = $N$$(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n)$ = $\infty$ = $N$($E_k$) = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$N$(E_n)$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu$($E_n)$

Comment: You are going to need "Tonelli's theorem for sums": if $a_{ij}$ is a doubly indexed sequence of nonnegative numbers (possibly infinite), then $\sum_i \sum_j a_{ij} = \sum_j \sum_i a_{ij}$ (including that if one sum diverges to infinity then so does the other).  With this in hand, it will not be necessary to consider the three cases separately.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Counting_Measure_is_Measure

Comment: @NateEldredge Like this? [Proving σ-additivity and interchanging order of summation/integration just because positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863937)